# Is creating Single Blob column to save BSON in MySQL serve purpose of Mongo DB database?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, rdbms

We were planning to use Mongo DB in one of small project; but it is suggested to use similar concept of JSON Modelling, which is used in Mongo DB and store it in MYSQL in BLOB and TEXT Types.

Is it a good idea to create Single Blob column to save JSON in MySQL Database?

```
ID   OPTLOCK   JSON_DATA   PROSESS_ID
 1       0       { }       2212
```

Answer (score 0):

First: BSON and JSON are not interchangeable. JSON would be stored in a TEXT field, because it is plain text, while BSON would go in a BLOB field, because it is binary data.

To your question, MongoDB is not just a key-value store that holds BSON data. It allows for indexing, querying, aggregating, pipelining, and map-reduce across documents because it understands the structure of the documents. Using MySQL as you describe would have no concept of what's in the TEXT/BLOB column - you could only efficiently store and retrieve documents by their IDs, and you could only update documents wholesale, whereas in MongoDB you can update and manipulate individual fields. The results of the two approaches would be drastically different.

Whether MongoDB or MySQL (or any other database) is more appropriate to your particular use case is a question that cannot be answered here.

Comment: But if we still use JSON in Text and also querying and manipulating of JSON is available in MySQL and one can also have feature of indexing in the same. But i am suspecting what advantage we have in MongoDB.

Comment: Querying JSON is available in MySQL in the `JSON` column type, not in `TEXT`. If you want to compare the functionality of the two, plenty of information is available on both on their websites.

Comment: I can query in TEXT too. Thanks for inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally considering storing rarely accessed and evolving data elements in MongoDB BSON form (extension of JSON) with compact representation (not wasting memory on Java object headers and alignment) on JVM client side and lazily turned to MongoDB Java format only if required. Some disadvantages: no native query support or indexing of content, may take even more space on server side, more complex code client side.
Anyway there are advantages of such approach and can be used for very specific applications e.g. JVM in-memory store loaded using Change Data Capture tools from RDBMS such as Amazon Aurora or Citus Data on Azure.